# How can I determine where in the square this point lies?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Hello all!
How can I mathematically prove that the red point is case 2 (inside the lower triangle)?
I need to figure this out for a computer game I'm working on. The red dot can wander around, but it cannot go on top of or beyond the four outer edges, so I don't need to worry about those scenarios. If the dot is directly on the diaganol line, we can just say that is case 1.

Comment: a point $(x, y)$ is in case 2 if $x + y > 1.$

Comment: Thanks, @abel! I can't believe how simple that was.

Comment: The assigning of coordinates of the square's vertices is rather odd...

Comment: @Timbuc, the y axis is often flipped in computer graphics because images are rendered line by line from top to bottom. I've gotten pretty used to upside down coordinate systems.

Comment: @DebrisHauler I see. Pretty weird for me, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your limiting curve is the diagonal line of the square. A line has an equation of the form $ax+by=c$. This equation is only defined up to multiplication by a constant, i.e. $adx+bdy=cd$ represents the same line for any $d\neq0$. So in your case you want a line which goes through $(1,0)$ and through $(0,1)$. One good choice would be $a=b=c=1$, i.e. the line $x+y=1$. Once you have the (implicit, not parametrized) equation for a curve, the distinction between the two sides of it can be made based on the corresponding inequatlities, i.e. $x+y\gtrless1$. Plug in a third point to see which side is which sign, and you will find that case 1 is $x+y<1$ and case 2 is $x+y>1$.

Comment: Can you explain why those inequalities correspond to whether the point is above or under the line? I didn't understand that part